# Laravel HTTP 500 Error after a while

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

I have problem with laravel in shared hosting. I deployed it on cPanel and was successfully running. After 4 or 5 hours I got HTTP 500 error. I checked error log and I figured out that some vendor files are removed given the following stacktrace:

> Uncaught class: Illumination\FileSystem\FileSystem.php

I placed my project folder before `public_html` and even edited index.php.

***UPDATE***

I ran `composer install` on localhost then uploaded files again. I gets back after some time. I think there is something wrong with server. Does anyone know?

Comment: It is a permission issue. Give full access to a folder then it will solve the issue.

Comment: Folders are all 755 and files are 644

Comment: Remove vendor folder and run "composer install" again.

Comment: Unfortunatly its on shared hosting. I've done that and it gets back after some time.

Comment: You can do it in your local then you can upload vendor folder.

Comment: As you said, it was working fine for a while.. Security features of some web hosting might be responsible for this issue, file might be flagged as malware and might be deleted by hosting, you can contact your hosting provider to help resolve this issue.

Comment: I gussed the problem K Arun Singh said. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it was working fine for a while.. Security features of some web hosting might be responsible for this issue, file might be flagged as malware and might be deleted by hosting, you can contact your hosting provider to help resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks the problem was hosting

Comment: welcome @Martin ZD, you can give me a thumbs up, if it saved your time :)